# Webgl / glsl чат

Tags: предложение, тематика, чат

В чатах ru so есть раздел, в котором задают вопросы и ищут ответы касательно svg, вроде живой, посему предлагаю создать сабж, готов поволонтерствовать там и рассказать страждущим как научиться рисовать при помощи этих технологий, хотя бы основы, что знаю сам, так сказать.

Если найдутся желающие, конечно же.

Возможный вариант первой темы для разъяснений - «Фрагментный шейдер или как научиться думать одним пикселем».

Comment: Ты можешь создать чат и не спрашивая :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вряд ли они на мете сидят =/

Comment: соглашусь, но и иных способов предложить предложенное не вижу, пусть так

Comment: гражданин желающий на месте.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106467/webgl-glsl

Comment: А почему именно Webgl? Оно ж от базового OpenGL не отличается в этом плане.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik из за возможности онлайн демонстраций, отличается, webgl это opengles 2.0, не дальше

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а, да, тогда разумно)